# How to send a message that automatically deletes with discord bot JS?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm wondering how I would be able to send my variable 'welcomeMessage' and delete it after such amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

you can delete messages like this;

`channel.send("This is my message").then((msg) => setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 5000));`

Note:

1000 ms = 1 sec.
5000 ms = 5 sec.
..